# How do I fix the black and white?

Tags: shaders

[image]

kind of new to blender, not sure what to do exactly could someone help me?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: You will need to include more details, is it a problem with your material? Is it something to do with texturing? (which it looks like it might be) Is it a problem with baking the lighting? Do you think its a problem with blender itself? Add more pictures too, that always helps.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the textures of materials, yes. Making pictures now

Comment: ADded one more picture since I cant add more than two

Comment: maybe normals problem (in edit mode select all and Ctrl+N)

Comment: Also try removing doubles, (Edit Mode > W > Remove Doubles). You could also add your blend file here so we can have a look at the file itself.

Comment: You may have duplicated your mesh on top of itself.

Comment: Tried all of it, as for Chebhou, this happened: http://i.imgur.com/3aRSCEW.png

Comment: For Matthew, it was the same result

Comment: Eh one more question, im trying to change the texture to metal, however nothing is happening http://i.imgur.com/Lpjw1yg.png

Comment: @gape write an answer of what worked for you